# at the time of downloading files from s3 bucket one file is not able to download

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-development-server

**anthi:_anti_hair_thinning_hair_spray.png**
this the file name in s3 when it downloaded using s3 client it save file with name anthi and with 0kb also file type shows file , wherever in s3 it is 100kb and file type is png

> I am using fs to save the file locally with same name please help me

```
 const objects = await s3.listObjectsV2(listParams).promise();
        for (const object of objects.Contents) {
            if (object.Size >= MIN_FILE_SIZE_IN_BYTES) {
                const fileKey = object.Key;
                const fileExtension = path.extname(fileKey).toLowerCase();
                if (allowedFileExtensions.includes(fileExtension)) {
                    const localFilePath = path.join(localDownloadFolder, path.basename(fileKey));
                    const data = await s3.getObject({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: fileKey }).promise();
                    fs.writeFileSync(localFilePath, data.Body);
                    // console.log(`File downloaded to: ${localFilePath}`);
                }
            }
        }
```

I will be very thankful for any suggestion or advice.

i tried to download files form asw s3 bucket

it is failing to download file name (anthi:_anti_hair_thinning_hair_spray.png ) with column

as using fs to write file in folder

how could i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is likely due to the colon (:) in the filename. You can try with this:

```
const objects = await s3.listObjectsV2(listParams).promise();
for (const object of objects.Contents) {
    if (object.Size >= MIN_FILE_SIZE_IN_BYTES) {
        const fileKey = object.Key;
        const fileExtension = path.extname(fileKey).toLowerCase();
        if (allowedFileExtensions.includes(fileExtension)) {
            // Replace colon and other invalid characters in the filename
            const sanitizedFileName = path.basename(fileKey).replace(/[:]/g, '_');
            const localFilePath = path.join(localDownloadFolder, sanitizedFileName);
            const data = await s3.getObject({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: fileKey }).promise();
            fs.writeFileSync(localFilePath, data.Body);
            // console.log(`File downloaded to: ${localFilePath}`);
        }
    }
}
```